# Движение элементов в зависимости от положения курсора

Tags: javascript, css

Есть блок:

```
<div class="data-bottom">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <p>CLOVER FOUND © 2001-2018 / Все права защищены.</p>
         <a href="lsweb.ru">Сайт разработан студией LiteSite</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать, чтобы элементы `<p />` и `<a />` двигались в зависимости от положения курсора на странице.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<sup>https://exmo.com/</sup>

Comment: чтобы отследить вхождение мыши в нужный блок, необходимо повесить обработчик на событие `mouseenter` `mouseleave` для этого блока.

Comment: блок получается вот этот data-bottom а уже "<p></p>" и "<a></a>" чтобы двигались как на exmo.com

Comment: Я не нашел, где и что там двигается. Либо скрипт не подгрузился. 3G у меня

Comment: когда на главной картинке водишь мышкой, анимация двигается в зависимости от положения мыши

Comment: там вот этот блок анимирован <canvas class="pg-canvas" style="display: block;" width="1343" height="495"></canvas>

Comment: Да, увидел. Я думаю, что там идет постоянной считывание положения курсора (относительно чего угодно, но скорее всего  - экрана), потом рассчитывается пройденное расстояние, полученный результат делится на какое-то число (уменьшается), после чего итоговое значение применяется  к анимируемым элементам

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы отследить вхождение мыши в нужный блок, необходимо повесить обработчик на событие mouseenter mouseleave для этого блока.

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("cont");

cont.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseenter);
cont.removeEventListener("mouseleave", mouseenter);

function mouseenter(){
 console.log("mouseenter");
}
```

```html
<div class="data-bottom">
<div  class="container" >
  <div id="cont" class="row" style="width:200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid ">
    <p>CLOVER FOUND © 2001-2018 / Все права защищены.</p>
    <a href="lsweb.ru">Сайт разработан студией LiteSite</a>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```